# Inbound Change Set from a Deleted Sandbox

Tags: deployment, sandbox

I have a question that I could not quite find the answer to on Google. So in my org we have a large change set that was sent over to the main Production box. We have not deployed it yet as there are some other pieces we need in place in Prod before deploy.

If the sandbox that this change set came from was deleted - would the Change Set still be available for Deployment? Or would it disappear from the Inbound Change Set list when the originating sandbox is deleted?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

This is what is mentioned in the documentation for [When Change Sets Become Unavailable](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=changesets_inbound_view_unavailable.htm&type=5):

> When the source sandbox is deleted or refreshed, assume that the change set is no longer available for deployment in the target org.

So in your scenario, if you delete the source sandbox, the change set will be no longer available in your production org as well.

The same section also mentions on the timing as when it becomes unavailable:

> A delay can occur between when the source sandbox is deleted or refreshed and when the target org shows the change set as unavailable. The length of the delay depends on how long it takes internal database cleanup processes to complete.

Answer (score 1):

We did an experiment(Not tested extensively) with the sandbox refresh on this recently!
Note: Take backups as necessary. And do your own experiment.

Change sets rely on packaging architecture and each changeset is essentially a package. An in-bound changeset was available for deployment, when we had the following conditions

- The changeset is **validated** at Destination Org and **pending deployment**
- Source Org is refreshed but **NOT ACTIVATED**
- The changeset has not expired

You can also perform a quick test that you can run without refreshing your sandbox, by simply creating uploading a changeset with some code, change the code on your sandbox before doing the deployment to on your prod, and check the result yourself.